# sample a lognormal distribution to an exact mean and sd

Tags: r

I've prepared a vector by sampling a log-normal distribution by (by trial and error) setting the parameters for `mean` and `sd` so `rlnorm()` returns exactly a **mean of 20** and a **sd of 6** (to 3 decimal places) for the any specified random `set.seed()` as per the following example...

```
# 10,000 samples from log-normal distribution

set.seed(7)
HcT <- rlnorm(n = 10000, log(19.147), log(1.33832))

# Report mean and sd

paste('The mean of HcT is',round(mean(HcT),3),'and the SD is',round(sd(HcT),3)) 

[1] "The mean of HcT is 20 and the SD is 6"
```

However, rather than trial and error I would like to 'goal seek' the two parameters. There are several stack overflow examples for [single value goal seek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174647/excel-goal-seek-in-r) but I'm not sure what function or package to apply for a two parameter case  (mean and SD in the above sample).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work OK to minimize the sum of the squared deviations from the target values. There are pitfalls to this approach (see e.g. *Numerical Recipes* by Press et al.), but it should be OK for simple problems.  The following code appears to retrieve the correct answers for your case:

```
f <- function(p,seed=7,target=c(20,6)) {
    mu <- log(p[1])
    sd <- log(p[2])
    set.seed(seed)
    r <- rlnorm(1e4,mu,sd)
    sum((c(mean(r),sd(r))-target)^2)
}
```

Choosing some non-ridiculous starting values ({15,2}):

```
optim(par=c(15,2), fn=f)
```

---

Based on @Cole's answer I would have thought this would work perfectly: draw normal deviates, transform them so they have a mean and sd *exactly* equal to the log-scale values, then exponentiate.  But it only works on average or asymptotically (i.e., a large sample converges to the desired mean), not exactly for finite samples. Haven't thought through exactly why this is so.

```
rlnorm_exact <- function(n, m, sd) {
    m2 <-  log(m^2 / sqrt(sd^2 + m^2))
    sd2 <- sqrt(log(1 + (sd^2 / m^2)))
    r <- c(scale(rnorm(n)))
    return(exp(sd2*r+m2))
}
```

Comment: Nice ... so if I set the output from optim(par=c(15,2), fn=f) to a variable say tmp then I can access the the parameters using tmp$par[1] for the mean and tmp$par[2] for the sd and feed them into the rlnorm() funciton

Comment: It's not exact because each distribution provided by ```rlnorm()``` might be weighted slightly differently than a different call. In other words, a six-sided die has an average of 3.5. Sometimes you may get a string of 1's. Just because a sample mean is lower than 3.5 does not prevent the population from having a mean of 3.5. More to the point, if you return m2 and sd2, that would be equivalent of ```log(19.147)``` and ```log(1.33832)```.

Comment: yes, but that's what the `scale()` call does -- sets the mean  and sd of the normal sample to exactly 0/1 ...

Comment: Ah, I see! I thought your edit was still returning mean and sd. Not sure what the OP prefers, but using ```rlnorm(n, m2, sd2)``` is a more random sample than always returning a sample with the same mean.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem before, too, and the link below set me straight. The `rlnorm()` isn't just simply using the log of the arithmatic mean and standard deviation. Instead, the function expects mu and sigma which are specific to the lognormal distribution.

Thankfully, the people at [this link](https://msalganik.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/making-sense-of-the-rlnorm-function-in-r/)  derived the formulas for us to transform to lognormal distributions.

I'm going to make this less pretty so people go to the link above as they solved this:

```
m <- 20
s <- 6

data_set <- rlnorm(n=1000000, 
                   meanlog=log(m^2 / sqrt(s^2 + m^2)), 
                   sdlog=sqrt(log(1 + (s^2 / m^2))))

mean(data_set)
sd(data_set)
```

Edit: changed variable from `sd` to `s` because `sd()` is also a function...

Comment: this is useful but doesn't quite do what the OP wanted, which is to get values that lead to *exact* matches with the target mean and sd ...

Comment: Based on his comment to your answer, I think this is exactly what OP wants - a lognormal distribution based on arithmetic mean and std. dev. So OP would end after the ```data_set``` call line.